# Cant extract single files from Tar, 0kb size, Java

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons-compress

I have been created a application which shall extract single files from tar-archive. The application reads the *.tar properly, but when i try to extract files, the application just create new files with correct filename... The files is empty (0kb). So... I probably just create new files instead of extract...

I'm a totally beginner at this point...

```
for(TarArchiveEntry tae : tarEntries){
    System.out.println(tarEntries.size());
    try {
        fOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File(tae.getFile(), tae.getName()));
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) tae.getSize()];
        int len;

        while ((len = tarFile.read(buf)) > 0) {
            fOutput.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        fOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is tarFile defined and what's in there? Shouldn't tae be referenced instead of tarFile.read(buf)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `tarFile` is a `TarArchiveInputStream` you can only read an entry's content right after calling `tarFile.getNextTarEntry()`.

The stream is processed sequentially, so when you invoke `getNextTarEntry` you skip over the content of the current entry right to the next entry.  It looks as if you had read the whole archive in order to fill `tarEntries` in which case you've already read past the last entry and the stream is exhausted.